# What' the differences between `chattr +i FILE` and `chmod -w FILE`?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

If the write permission of the file is disabled, no one can change the file.

The `chattr +i FILE` also can protect the file from change.

Let me know what the difference, and when we should use `chattr +i` rather than `chown -w`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`chattr +i` sets the `immutable` filesystem attribute on the file. It differs from access control rules. Access control rules apply to the file attributes, while `immutable` is a filesystem **extended** file attribute, which may not be available on all filesystems. Only a user with root privileges can set or unset this extended attribute. Nobody, not even the owner or a user with write permission,  can write into such file. A user without write file permission can create a hard link to a regular file, but if the file is marked as immutable, a user cannot create a hard link, since the filesystem cannot change the references count to this immutable file.

`chattr +i` is useful for protection from accidental deletion by root. Also an immutable file cannot be renamed or moved from one directory to another.

Comment: I found the benefit to use 'chattr -i'. We can protect the file without taking care of owner, permissions and whatever. just execute 'chattr -i'.

Comment: Then, Do you have strong reason to do 'chattr -i' to a file(root root chmod==444) ?

Comment: @EffectiveBugs If you want to protect a file from deletion even by root, the `chattr +i` is useful.

Answer (score 6):

From `chattr` man page

> A  file  with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data
>   can be written to the file.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this
>   attribute.

As you can see , *chattr* is more powerful than *chmod*. **chmod -w** removes only '`write`' permission to the file content. And also you need to use `chattr +i` to protect/lock the file then `chattr -i` to unlock

Answer (score 1):

`chmod -w file` is available on all UNIX environment, however `chattr -i FILE` using extended file attributes might not be available on your system, depending on the type of the File System/Distro!

Apart from that, have a look at [this link](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/pages/extattrs.html) for the good and bad points of employing extended file attributes.